# Sci-fi book: female character and her brother repeat their mantra (periodic table, Fibonacci sequence) to avoid their consciousness being sucked

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this story when I was younger (middle school), I don't remember much of it as it was a very long time ago.

From what I remember the main character is female and she has a younger brother. They are with another traveler whom I believe was related to them.

At one point in the book their consciousness were being attacked or sucked into a void and in order to protect themselves they each had their own type mantra they repeated. The girl repeated the periodic table and I believe the traveler repeated either the Fibonacci sequence or listed off prime numbers. Her brother on the other hand had been captured in the exchange.

Answer (score 7):

One of my Facebook friends recognized it. Madeleine L'Engle's *[Wrinkle In Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wrinkle_in_Time)* series (1962) for any of those trying to figure it out.

> Troughout the novel, the young main characters Meg Murry, Charles Wallace Murry, and Calvin O'Keefe embark on a journey through space and time, from universe to universe, as they endeavor to save their father and the world. The novel offers a glimpse into the battles between light and darkness, and goodness and evil, as the young characters mature into adolescents on their journey. The novel wrestles with questions of spirituality and purpose, as the characters are often thrown into conflicts of love, divinity, and goodness.

Comment: You can accept your own answer in about 48 hours. :) We'd like it if you did.